# How to inject environment variables in jenkinsfile using shared libraries before beginning the pipeline code?

Tags: environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to inject multiple environment variables using shared libraries into multiple jenkinsfile, as the env variables are common across these multiple jenkinsfile. Motive is to inject properties at a global level so that the variables are global and accessible throughout the pipeline.

I have tried the following:
a. Used the environment tag in jenkinsfile. This is required to be done in all the jenkinsfile, hence no code re-usability.
b. I am able to inject env variables inside the script tag of a stage. But I want to do it before the pipeline code begins. This will be like global properties which can be accessed from anywhere in the pipeline.

Instead of the below:

//Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
environment {
TESTWORKSPACE="some_value"
BUILDWORKSPACE="some_value"
...
...
30+ such env properties
}
}
```

I am looking for something where I can declare these env variables in a shared library groovy script and then access it throughout the pipeline. Something like below:

//Jenkinsfile

```
def call(Map pipelineParams) {

pipeline {
<code>
<Use pipelineParams.TESTWORKSPACE as a variable anywhere in my pipeline>
}
}
```

Comment: Did you find any  solution for this? I have the same issue and haven't figured out yet how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible. Maybe your jenkinsfile could be something like :

```
@Library(value="my-shared-lib@master", changelog=false) _

import com.MyClass

def extendsEnv(env) {
  def myClass = new MyClass()
  myClass.getSharedVars().each { String key, String value -> 
    env[key] = value 
  }
}

pipeline {
  ...
  stage('init') {
    steps {
      extendsEnv(env)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that your shared vars should be string values if you plan to add them as environment variable later. But I didn't try this code.
You could also imagine another solution : factorize the pipeline for all teams and use parameters override system (project level > team leavel > global level) :

```
@Library(value="my-shared-lib@master", changelog=false) _
      
def projectConfig = [:]
projectConfig['RESOURCE_REQUEST_CPU'] = '2000m'
projectConfig['RESOURCE_LIMIT_MEMORY'] = '2000Mi'

teamPipeline(projectConfig)
```

teamPipeline function is declared in the shared lib in vars directory, with additionnal teams parameters, which finaly calls a common pipeline with a parameter map. You set those parameters as env var as shown above.